# Does there exist a function in $B_{\infty,1}^{1/2}\setminus H^{1/2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces, besov-space

Does there exist a function in $B_{\infty,1}^{1/2}([0,1])\setminus H^{1/2}([0,1])$? If so can it be constructed explicitly?

A reference will be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you define $B^{1/2}_{\infty,1}$? I assume one takes $s=1/2,$ $p=\infty,$ $q=1$ (following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besov_space), but then unless I'm mistaken this space is contained in $H^{1/2}.$

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of Besov spaces. Why should such inclusion should be true?

Comment: On bounded domains one has the the inclusions $B^s_{p_1,q_1} \subset B^s_{p_2,q_2}$ if $p_1 \geq p_2$ and $q_1 \leq q_2,$ which gives $B^{1/2}_{\infty,1} \subset B^{1/2}_{2,2} =H^{1/2}.$